# BIN Ranges for Payment Information

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

I am looking to test the Payment API I have built. Does anyone have the BIN ranges for.  Can someone list the bin codes for VISA and American Express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact database of BINs (IINs) is a rare beast. You might try the basic rules, as in the [library](https://github.com/PawelDecowski/jquery-creditcardvalidator):

```
 {
    name: 'amex',
    pattern: /^3[47]/,
    valid_length: [15]
  }, {
    name: 'diners_club_carte_blanche',
    pattern: /^30[0-5]/,
    valid_length: [14]
  }, {
    name: 'diners_club_international',
    pattern: /^36/,
    valid_length: [14]
  }, {
    name: 'jcb',
    pattern: /^35(2[89]|[3-8][0-9])/,
    valid_length: [16]
  }, {
    name: 'laser',
    pattern: /^(6304|670[69]|6771)/,
    valid_length: [16, 17, 18, 19]
  }, {
    name: 'visa_electron',
    pattern: /^(4026|417500|4508|4844|491(3|7))/,
    valid_length: [16]
  }, {
    name: 'visa',
    pattern: /^4/,
    valid_length: [16]
  }, {
    name: 'mastercard',
    pattern: /^(5[1-5]|2[2-7])/
    valid_length: [16]
  }, {
    name: 'maestro',
    pattern: /^(5018|5020|5038|6304|6759|676[1-3])/,
    valid_length: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
  }, {
    name: 'discover',
    pattern: /^(6011|622(12[6-9]|1[3-9][0-9]|[2-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-1][0-9]|92[0-5]|64[4-9])|65)/,
    valid_length: [16]
  }
```

See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number) (sorry for the obvious), and an online tool to [recognize the issuer](https://binlist.net/).

Comment: For the record, laser cards have been withdrawn now, although the above would allow you to recognise them as such, which at least one Payment-Gateway has required me to do :-)